# Cannot get new connection from pool

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose

I use the elasticsearch Ruby gem and docker compose for my containers.
After startup from my Ruby app I get this error:

> Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Error: Cannot get new connection from pool.
>   web_1      |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-transport-2.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:249:in `perform_request'
>   web_1      |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-transport-2.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in`perform_request'
>   web_1      |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-transport-2.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:128:in `perform_request'
>   web_1      |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-api-2.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/api/namespace/common.rb:21:in`perform_request'
>   web_1      |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-api-2.0.0/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/cluster/health.rb:52:in `health'
>   web_1      |   /usr/src/app/lib/search_model/adapters/elastic_search_adapter.rb:11:in`initialize'

The initialize method looks like this:

```
  def initialize(params={})
    @client = Elasticsearch::Client.new params[:config].merge(host: ::ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_HOST'])
    client.transport.reload_connections!
    client.cluster.health # <-- Line 11
  end
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

[EDIT]
To check if the es server is availiable I do this in my startup skript:

```
until nc -vz $ELASTICSEARCH_HOST 9200; do
 echo "Elasticsearch is not ready, sleeping..."
 sleep 1
done
```

Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  # postgres:
  #   image: postgres
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    volumes:
      - .conf/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    expose:
      - "6379"
  elastic:
    image: elasticsearch:alpine
    expose:
      - "9200"
      - "9300"
    volumes:
      - elastic:/usr/share/elastic/data
      - .conf/elastic/synonyms:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/synonyms
  web:
    build: .
    command: sh bin/docker-start.sh
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elastic
      - RACK_ENV=production
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 4300:2300
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -vz elastic 9200 && nc -vz elastic 9200
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 6
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - elastic
    links:
      - redis
      - elastic

volumes:
  elastic: {}
```

Comment: Are you sure ES server has been started and is accessible without Ruby, e.g. using curl?

Comment: Yes. I've edited the post to show my startup skript.

Comment: do you have access to port 9300 from your server where this app runs? usually the transport will actually connect not to the http port(9200) but instead using the native Elasticsearch transport protocol that usually runs on 9300

Comment: I now have explicitly exposed the port 9200 and the port 9300 in my compose file and it didn't change. (See edit)
But in the meantime I found out that it only happens if I use typhoeus as the adapter